# Creating matrix with sequential numbers in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, matrix

I used two for loops for this and i stuck in here;

```
size = int(input("size? : "))

matrix = list(range(size**2))

for i in range(size):
    for j in range(size):
        print(j, end=" ")
     print()
```

and my output is;

```
size? : 3
0 1 2 
0 1 2 
0 1 2
```

How can I make it look like;

```
0 1 2
3 4 5
6 7 8
```

But it has to be work for any number that i gave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't expect to print values from `0-9` without using the `matrix` variable, you just print `j` everytime which is range of size, that's normal, you may use `matrix` :

```
for i in range(size):
    for j in range(size):
        print(matrix[i * size + j], end=" ") 
        # print(f'{matrix[i * size + j]:>2d}', end=" ") to format 2 digit numbers
    print()
```

This also works

```
for idx in range(0, len(matrix), size):
    print(*matrix[idx:idx + size])
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That helped a lot. And I have also a follow-up question. Is there any way that I can make output of numbers centered. For example when I make the size 4 last two rows are moving right.

Comment: @SamFatu I've just edit for this, the '2' in `>2d` means 'padd befor with space to reach size of 2 at all, so if you have 3 digits at a moment use '3'

Answer (score 1):

```
size = int(input("size? : "))

for i in range(size):
    for j in range(i*size, i*size+size):
        print(j, end=" ")
    print()
```

Comment: Is there any way that I can make output of numbers centered. For example when I make the size 4 last two rows are moving right.

Comment: yes, replace the 4th line with `print('%3d' % j, end=" ")`